# Want to create the automation script for Swap

Tags: bash

Hello Community Members,

I want to create the script that script check if the memory usage is high in percentage, do not turn off swap memory; however, if the memory usage is low in percentage, not critical, turn off swap memory, sleep 1, and turn on swap memory again.

How to create this script?

Comment: Have you tired anything? or not? if yes put your *code** in your question.

Comment: I know the command, cat /proc/meminfo, free -l; however, I want to grep the percentage with Bash, and check if the memory usage is high in bash.

Comment: What is your concern that makes you want to do this?  It might be a question for SuperUser whether this is a good idea.  If you have swap turned on it will only be used when needed.  If it is off and you need it, then you could have processes die.

Comment: Swap memory usage is always high. Therefore, I want to create the automate scripts that prevents the high usages of Swap Memory.

Comment: Is there anyone who can help to generate the script to mange the percentages of SWAP automatically?